# post and get attribute in ASP.NET action method

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have two create action methods, one for get method, one for post method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{  
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{  
   return View();
}
```

If I just add a view to Get method, so there is no view for Post action method, so when I invoke the post method of Create, why I still get the view that belongs to the get method?

Comment: `return View();` returns the view with the same name as the method, in your case `Create.cshtml`

Comment: you cannot create two method with same signature. You will get build error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but if I want to add a view for the post method, I can't actually do it because it already has the same name view for the get method. So what should I do?

Comment: You can always use `return View("NameOfAnotherView");` (but not clear why you would want to do that - you should be redirecting to another method if you want to return a different view)

Comment: I think you should pass parameter in `[HttpPost] Create()` method.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a View from a method, this view belongs to all methods with the same name and that share the same class.
If you want to call another view (In this case, from the post method), just use

```
return View("nameOfTheView");
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to the view is inferred from the name of the controller and the name of the controller action.

If you prefer, you can be explicit about the view. The following line of code returns a view named Foo:

```
return  View("Foo");
```

so, you should specify the name of view that you want to return